# Questions about some special classes of polynomials

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, fourier-analysis, roots

Consider natural numbers as coefficients $a_i\in \mathbb{N}_0$.

 Consider the polynomials $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}a_iX^i + X^m$.

Note that $a_i\in \mathbb{N}_0$.

> <strike>**Question 1:** What are classical results concerning these polynomials and their roots which distinguish them from all the other?</strike>

Consider the functions $f_{nm}(x) = nx\ \%\ m$ which sends $0 \leq x < m$ to the residue of $nx$ modulo $m$.
Consider the polynomials $\sum_{x=0}^{m-1}f_{nm}(x)X^x + X^m$. 
Note that  $f_{nm}(x)\in \mathbb{N}_0$.

> **Question 2:** Is anything general known about (the roots of) *these* polynomials?

Consider the [Fourier transform](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321685/fourier-analysis-of-nx-m?noredirect=1#comment802222_321685) $\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)$ of $f_{nm}(x)$. 
Consider the polynomials $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)X^k + X^m$. 
Note that in general $\tilde{f}_{nm}(k)\in \mathbb{C}$.

> **Question 3:** What can be said about *these* polynomials (if anything)?

Consider the $m$ roots $\zeta(k)$, $k = 0,\dots,m-1$, of any polynomial of degree $m$. 
Consider the polynomials $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\zeta({\pi(k)})X^k + X^m$ for some permutation $\pi$ of the roots. 
Note that in general $\zeta(k)\in \mathbb{C}$.

> **Question 4:** What can be said about *these* polynomials (if anything)?

Consider the Fourier transform $\tilde{\zeta}(x)$ of the roots $\zeta(k)$ of any polynomial. 
Consider the polynomials $\sum_{x=0}^{m-1}\tilde{\zeta}(\pi(x))X^x + X^m$ for some permutation $\pi$ of the FT.

Note that in general $\tilde{\zeta}(x)\in \mathbb{C}$.

> **Question 5:** What can be said about *these* polynomials (if anything)?

Comment: To the close voter: I disagree in having asked a too broad question: I immediately got a concise answer to the first of exactly five questions (which I could "close" immediatley).

Comment: But I admit: 5 questions may be too broad for 1 question. (But admittedly they belong strongly to each other.)

Comment: It would be good just to pose one question each time, yes.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1: Since they are monic polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$, the roots are algebraic integers.  Of course none of the roots are positive reals, nor do they have conjugates which are positive reals.

Comment: Fair enough! So I can put a check mark at question 1.

Comment: Isn't there any difference with respect to "all coefficients being integers" or "being positive integers"?

Comment: That's where the "none of the roots being positive reals..." comes in.  I don't know about a necessary and sufficient condition, though.